# NodeJS API Rest 404 not found instead cannot get

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404

Hy Guys i try to make a simple API but i would like do something thani can't cuz i just learn nodejs not long. I would like than instead the api display

> Cannot Get /ROUTE

Display this

> {
>       "code": 404,
>       "message": "Not found"
>   }

Att All routes.

My code :

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'restapi',
  port     : '8889'
});


connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Congrats you are connected')
})

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

var server = app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port

console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

});

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
// CORS headers

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
// Set custom headers for CORS
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end();
} else {
    next();
 }
});

//GET Domains
app.get('/api/domains.json', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  connection.query('select * from domain', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var user = results[0];
  if (user == undefined) {
      res.status(404);
      res.send({
          code: 404,
          message: "Not found"
      });
  } else {
      res.send({
          code: 200,
          message: 'success',
          datas: results
      });
    }
 });
 });
```

So its just one request for the moment but i will try to add POST, PUT and Delete, juste make a simple CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

I see one thing that can affect expected behaviour. You are declaring a more general route before the most specific one.

This one is so generic, that is going to treat all requests

> app.all('/*',

And this one is included in the previous one, so noone request is going to be treated here.

> app.get('/api/domains.json',

Try to change the order of both routes, and tell me if it changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end();
} else {
  res.status(404);
  res.send({
      code: 404,
      message: "Not found"
  });
}
```

I change the conditions and it works.